# Solving picture puzzle with python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-2.7

> You have 2000 raw images, 52x52 pixels, RGB 24 bits, that correspond
>   to the pieces of a puzzle representing a 4000x1250 pixel image.
>
> Each adjacent pair of images overlap on 1 row/column of pixels. Border
>   images have a duplicated row/column of pixels. Try to rebuild the
>   puzzle.

I'm thinking of using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), maybe other libraries

**EDIT**

someone has done it this way

```
private function runAlgorithm(index:int):void
{
    var currentBitmap:Object = allBitmaps[index];
    if(currentBitmap.visited) return;
    currentBitmap.visited = true;

    var left:int = leftMap[currentBitmap.leftRow];
    var right:int = rightMap[currentBitmap.rightRow];
    var top:int = topMap[currentBitmap.topRow];
    var bottom:int = bottomMap[currentBitmap.bottomRow];

    if(left != -1){
        allBitmaps[left].bitmap.x = currentBitmap.bitmap.x - 50;
        runAlgorithm(left);
    }
    if(right != -1){
        allBitmaps[right].bitmap.x = currentBitmap.bitmap.x + 50;
        runAlgorithm(right);
    }
    if(top != -1){
        allBitmaps[top].bitmap.y = currentBitmap.bitmap.y - 50;
        runAlgorithm(top);
    }
    if(bottom != -1){
        allBitmaps[bottom].bitmap.y = currentBitmap.bitmap.y + 50;
        runAlgorithm(bottom);
    }
}
```

If that's the correct way, I will need to write a similar or code in python

Comment: I'm using the `homework` tag, it's not a homework but it looks like a homework :) anyway i just want to know how to approach it :D

Comment: I removed the `homework` tag, if it's not homework don't add it.

Comment: If they overlap eachother by just 1 piXel row/column, then how can corner and side pieces, be 52x52. either corner/side images arent 52x52 or they overlap more... this is important to know, because if the pieces of the puzzle are overlapping by more than 1 row/column, then you have to compare 2 columns/rows of pixels to get positive match. but if side and corner pieces are smaller - then its relatively easy to weed them out of the rest. Basically you know the "grid" size- 25x80. create objects of those images and create hashes of the overlaping areas. create borders of the puzzle by matching t

Comment: true, I am waiting for the guy who created the puzzle to reply and explain that since yesterday

Comment: I suggest the “Feynman Problem Solving Algorithm”: 1. Write down the problem. 2. Think very hard. 3. Write down the answer. ;-)

Comment: The assignment mentions that border pieces have a duplicate row/column of pixels at the edge side. So finding the border images is still quite easy, though you might get false positives.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a computer vision problem to me. PIL sounds like a good choice though.

Comment: And I agree: the creator should have said the images are overlapping in 2 rows/columns, assuming (based on the total size of the puzzle) each image contains 50x50 pixels of data that actually matters.

Comment: @nightcracker please read my edit

Comment: @noah1989 please read my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using numpy I would make a big matrix out of the small 52x52 matrixes. Each entry would be a 3 element tuple `(R, G, B)`.

To join the smaller matrixes you can use [hstack](https://web.archive.org/web/20120408144109/http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#hstack) ([def](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)) and [vstack](https://web.archive.org/web/20120408144109/http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#vstack) ([def](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)).